# In The Half-Blood Prince, there are many tragic events happening because of Voldemort. Did these events happen in real life?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Half-Blood Prince*, Fudge mentions that it appears as though a hurricane has happened (actually caused by giants) and a bridge collapsed. Did these events (along with several murders) actually happen in real life? Or are they purely fiction in J.K. Rowling's story?

Comment: In a word, no. There were no notable hurricanes or bridge collapses during the near time that Rowling was writing the books. There had been a substantial (and in modern times unprecedented) storm in 1987 that she may have been drawing inspiration from.

Comment: Pretty much every bridge collapse in UK has been a rail bridge, and as a result of a rail crash on said bridge; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Bridge_disasters_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: @Valorum That's what the wizards want you to think...

Comment: @Exal, I agree! Perhaps we don't know of some interesting happenings! Which is why I wanted to ask . . .

Comment: The Millennium Bridge, which in the movie collapsed, did have a harmonic oscillation problem when first opened. The bridge is depicted initially swaying (in reality, the bridge did exhibit a very noticeable sway) progressing to collapse (an outcome pedestrians on the real bridge may have feared, but never actually happened). The real bridge was subsequently fitted with damping devices to address the sway problem. I'm not clear on timeline here, but one might imagine the sway issue feeding inspiration for the movie, and impressionable children on the real bridge in fear of a magical attack.

Comment: @AnthonyX - Subsequent testing shows that the 'sway' was well within the bridge's design tolerance and that there was zero danger of collapse

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I didn't think there was any danger of collapse, just perception in the minds of people, such as those experiencing the sway. If you've seen any video of people crossing it, the motion seems to have been enough to make walking on it at least unpleasant if not challenging; that's what the dampers were installed to address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book takes place in 1996-1997, so the conversation that tells us that these events happened takes place in July of 1996.

The Brockdale Bridge is an invention of the author because there are no bridges in the UK called that.

In the film, the bridge is the Millennium Bridge, which was built between 1998 and 2000 (two years after the film's events take place) and is still intact.

Hurricanes in Europe are rare, but can happen. In 1996, the only hurricane that affected the United Kingdom was [Hurricane Lili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Lili_(1996)), but this took place in November, months after the conversation in the books.

So no, the events in the book are fictional.

Comment: not really, the book is written between 2003 and 2005 so J.K. Rowling may know them when she write this chapter.